# Plugin: Making a record's dateUpdated column update to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: plugin-development, database, records

When creating a record in a plugin it automatically creates `dataCreated` and `dataUpdated` columns.  However, it doesn't look like the `dataUpdated` columns is updated `on update`.

Is there a way to set the `dataUpdated` column attribute to `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Or is that column manually updated in the background when using active record's `update()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you inserting the data?

If you're inserting data through any of Craft's [Active Record](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference#craft.app.records) or [DbCommand](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/db/DbCommand) classes (`craft()->db->createCommand()`), then Craft will take of updating `dateUpdated` for you.

If you're using raw SQL, then you'll have to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. In prototyping I updated a record through phpMyAdmin and noticed it didn't have the `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute. If it's taken care of with `update()` it's fine.